# Jenkins build fails when it gets to Deploy to GKE Cluster

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine

Some of the projects were accidentally deleted 1 month ago and I was able to notice it and restore them before the 30day period to get fully deleted.

But right now I am not able to build anything for production as I get this error..

The 34.xxx.xxx.xxx ip that I redacted is the external endpoint of the GKE production cluster.
The jenkins is also on GKE but in a different project.

```html
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Failed to launch command args: [kubectl, --kubeconfig, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Release Manager - Go - PROD/pim-api@tmp/.kube1514839246644114611config, apply, --namespace, default, -f, /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Release Manager - Go - PROD/pim-api/deployments/k8s/init-job.yaml], status: 1. Logs: Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout

    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubectlWrapper.launchAndJoinCommand(KubectlWrapper.java:174)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubectlWrapper.runKubectlCommand(KubectlWrapper.java:138)
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.k8sengine.KubernetesEngineBuilder.perform(KubernetesEngineBuilder.java:267)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you pull new credentials for the GKE cluster and pass them to Jenkins ? It's not clear if your pipeline does that automatically or if you are backing them statically into your jenkins config. I'm talking about the kubeconfig file.

Also are you using control plane authorised network on the GKE side ?

Comment: I just saw the response, yes the issue for the production cluster was from the control plane authorised network on the GKE side I had to add the new IP there.